# Byte typecasting in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, addition

the program gives me loss of precision error but i cant think of any precision loss since numbers are small

### This is the code ##

```
 class Demo  
 {  
   public static void main(String args[])  
   {  
      byte b1=3;  
      byte b2=2;  
      byte b3=b1+b2;  
      System.out.println(b3);  
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Does this compile? Why don't you just use `int`?

Comment: First rules of SO: If you have error messages or stack traces, include them in your post (use code formatting). If you have output, include it in your post, along with the input and expected output.  Also read the [FAQ] and [Ask]

Comment: This example comes straight from the OCJP java book..The solution is even included..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The addition expression `b1 + b2` is of type `int` - there aren't any addition operators defined on smaller types than `int`. So in order to convert that back to a `byte`, you have to cast:

```
byte b3 = (byte) (b1 + b2);
```

Note that although *you* happen to know that the values are small, the compiler doesn't care about the values you've set in the previous two lines - they could both be 100 for all it knows. Likewise although *you* know that the `int` you're trying to assign to a `byte` variable is only the result of adding two `byte` values together (or rather, two values promoted from `byte` to `int`), the expression as a whole is just `int` and could have come from anywhere as far as the language is concerned.

(The fact that the addition can overflow is a separate matter, but that would be an inconsistent argument - after all, you can add two `int` values together and store the result in an `int` variable, even though the addition could have overflowed easily.)

Answer (score 3):

Because 127 is the last value of byte.
Assume b1 = 127 and b2 = 2

now what happends b = b1+b2 = 129 [which is out of byte range, i.e. it's in int range]

now if you cast it b = (byte)(b1+b2), you will get -127 this is due to rounding of the value to byte.

Answer (score 3):

```
    byte b1=3;
    byte b2=2;
    byte b3=b1+b2;  // you can't use byte here, Every time addition will result 
                     int value
```

Because, If you trying to cast an int which is larger than byte range, there is a loss part of that value. So addition will not allow to use byte here.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you do +,-,*,/,%
java internally uses a function

ex: max(int,dataType of operand 1,dataType of operand 2);

here in your code
max(int, byte,byte) ==> which one is bigger ? ==> **int** is bigger

so you may get POSSIBLE LOSS OF PRESSION
found :int

required : byte

Another Example

```
 short a =10;
 byte b=20;
 short c = a+b;
```

now:

internally: max(int,OP1,OP2);

ie max(int,short,byte) ==> which is bigger Data Type? **int**

so java excepts **int**

```
 int c = a+b;  (works fine)
```

Another Example  :

```
 long a =10;
 byte b=20;
 short c = a+b;
```

now:

internally: max(int,OP1,OP2);

ie max(int,long,byte) ==> which is bigger Data Type? **long**

so java excepts **long**

```
 long c = a+b;(works fine)
```

Another Example:

```
byte b = 10;
b = b+1;
```

now,
max(int,byte)==> which is bigger Data Type ? **int**
so,

```
int c = b+1;(works fine) or b = (byte) b+1;
```

hope you understand